# Retrieving Key From Map In Scala Using A Value

Tags: scala, dictionary

i currently have a Map in scala and I need to retrieve the key (or keys!) which match a certain value.

I currently have a map of students and test scores and need to be able to find the students who have scored the value that I input.

My map is as follows:

```
var students = Map(
 "Neil" -> 87
 "Buzz" -> 71
 "Michael" -> 95
)
```

How could I search through this map to find the student who had scored 71 for example and then return the key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? :)

Comment: I've tried lots of map methods but they all seem to be concerned with retriving the value based on the key rather than the other way about.

Comment: Like `students.filter { (key, value) => value > 50 }` ?

Comment: @insan-e you'll need a `case` in there: `students.filter{case (k,v) => v > 50}`

Comment: @evan058 I think not, `T` of `Map` is a `Tuple2`: `trait Map[A, +B] extends Iterable[(A, B)] ...`. Also in docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.x/index.html#scala.collection.Map@filter(p:A=>Boolean):Repr). ;)

Comment: @insan-e Yes, it is an iterable of `Tuple2`s but you can't unpack them that way. Trying to do so gives a `error: missing parameter type
Note: The expected type requires a one-argument function accepting a 2-Tuple. Consider a pattern matching anonymous function, '{ case (a, b) =>  ... }'` The error even says to use `case`

Comment: @evan058 My bad, no hard feelings.. xD Guess it's time to get some sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you should probably be using a `val` instead of the `var`, like this: `val students = Map("Neil" -> 97, "Buzz" -> 71, "Michael" -> 95)`

Secondly, the method you probably want is called `find`.

Something like this `students.find(_._2 == 71).map(_._1)`

Which basically says, find me the first (key, value) pair where the value `(_._2 == 71)` is 71, and then throw out the value `.map(_._1)`. It's going to be wrapped in an Option because there might be 0 matches.

That said, unless you have something to ensure a value never appears more than once, you might be happier with the results from `filter`.

Comment: Answer may have been edited: "I need to retrieve the key (or keys!)". So it looks like `filter` is the correct option

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code to achieve this

```
students.filter(_._2 == 71).map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

```
 val students = Map("N" -> 87, "B" -> 71, "M" -> 95, "X" -> 95)
 students.filter(_._2 == 95).keys
 res3: Iterable[String] = Set(M, X)
```

Comment: can someone explain what's within the filter function

Answer (score -1):

**Concise and clear**

Just collect name of the student with a given score.

```
 student collect { case (name, 10) => name} headOption
```

use `Collect`

```
val students = Map("Scala" -> 10, "Haskell" -> 20, "frege" -> 30)

student collect { case (name, 10) => name} headOption
```

The above code collects the name of the person whose score is 10 and then do headOption to get the first person. The above code returns None if there is no match.

**Scala REPL output**

```
scala> val students = Map("Scala" -> 10, "Haskell" -> 20, "frege" -> 30)
students: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Scala -> 10, Haskell -> 20, frege -> 30)

scala> students collect { case (name, 10) => name }
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(Scala)

scala> students collect { case (name, 10000) => name }
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List()

scala> students collect { case (name, 10) => name } headOption
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res5: Option[String] = Some(Scala)
```